# How to convert NSDictionary in objective c to Swift?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

I have this NSDictionary in Objective c class and when I try convert to Swift, I get errors uncaught exception in appendString nil argument

```
 NSDictionary *plainPart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"text/plain; charset=UTF-8",kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,data,kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,@"8bit",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];

  testMsg.parts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:plainPart,nil];
```

Try to Sift:

```
  var plainPart: NSDictionary = ["text/plain; charset=UTF-8":kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey, self.data: kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey, "8bit": kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey]

    msg.parts = [plainPart]
```

What is incorrect in the code conversion?

Thanks!

Comment: what exactly is "self.data"? A String?

Comment: maybe because this string is empty?

Comment: I declare this: var data = "" but then is a string like "some_word". not is empty. I was answering that was string type, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may have the keys and values backwards. Try this:

```
var plainPart: NSDictionary = [kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey: "text/plain; charset=UTF-8", kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey: self.data , kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey : "8bit"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
var plainPart: NSDictionary = ["text/plain; charset=UTF-8":kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey, self.data: kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey, "8bit": kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil]
```

I also head an exception, after adding nil  as last argument the exception was gone.